# Satisfying Periodic Boundary Conditions while plotting spherical particles inside a cube

Tags: matlab, boundary-conditions, plotting

I am trying to plot spherical particles in a cube of fixed dimension in matlab. I face a problem here where the center of the sphere is too close to the edge of the cube in this case the rest of the sphere needs to be plotted in the opposite side. I hope I am clear. How can I do this

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/CCC_crystal_cell_(opaque).svg/1092px-CCC_crystal_cell_(opaque).svg.png)?

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty solution is to plot a *phantom* sphere outside the cube on the opposite side, and then apply clipping to the cube boundary.